# How does margin and border work together within an element?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, border, margin

My goal in this question is to understand how these properties really work since I get results different from what I was expecting. I found workarounds to my problem (like setting a very thin border) but what I want is to really understand why this doesn't do what I expected.

[This jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/salvarico/gvkybua8/1/) exemplifies my problem.

I was expecting this code to have the whole section element displayed in the window and not needing to scroll down as the code snippet shows. This code has a white space in the top which I didn't expected.

I can see that [the default style for `<p>` tags has `margin-top: 1em`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_p.asp) but since margin is transparent I was expecting to show a blue background in the margin area. By commenting out line 22 of the CSS code I set `margin-top: 0;` and this solves the problem but I don't understand why since `margin` is transparent.

I can also fix the problem by commenting out line 12 in the CSS code and setting a thin border to the `section` element. I don't understand why a thin border can solve this issue.

Finally, one more issue here is that if I delete the `c` content from the `p` element something changes because commenting line 22 doesn't fix the problem with the white margin at the top.